# Indexing duplicates with respect to certain variables

Tags: r, if-statement, indexing, duplicates

I want to index duplicates with respect to certain variables in R in a seperate, new variable. 
Let's assume that I have the following dataset:

```
a <- seq(from=0, to=1, by=.4)
b <- seq(from=0, to=1, by=.4)
c <- seq(from=0, to=1, by=.4)
d <- seq(from=0, to=1, by=.4)

df <- expand.grid(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d)

> df[1:20,]
     a   b   c d
1  0.0 0.0 0.0 0
2  0.4 0.0 0.0 0
3  0.8 0.0 0.0 0
4  0.0 0.4 0.0 0
5  0.4 0.4 0.0 0
6  0.8 0.4 0.0 0
7  0.0 0.8 0.0 0
8  0.4 0.8 0.0 0
9  0.8 0.8 0.0 0
10 0.0 0.0 0.4 0
11 0.4 0.0 0.4 0
12 0.8 0.0 0.4 0
13 0.0 0.4 0.4 0
14 0.4 0.4 0.4 0
15 0.8 0.4 0.4 0
16 0.0 0.8 0.4 0
17 0.4 0.8 0.4 0
18 0.8 0.8 0.4 0
19 0.0 0.0 0.8 0
20 0.4 0.0 0.8 0
```

In this case, the first entry and the tenth entry are identical with respect to a and b. How can I assign a value e.g. "0.00-0.00" to a new variable for all those columns that have this combination (also line 19) and the same for all other combinations (eg. line 2, 11 and 20 etc.).

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get duplicated rows like 10th,11th...

```
duplicated(df[,c(1,2)])
```

getting original rows as well ie. 1st,2nd...

```
duplicated(df[,c(1,2)], fromLast = TRUE)
```

assigning range to original as well as duplicates in new column `e`

```
df[duplicated(df[,c(1,2)], fromLast = TRUE) | duplicated(df[,c(1,2)]),"e"] <- paste0(df[duplicated(df[,c(1,2)], fromLast = TRUE) | duplicated(df[,c(1,2)]),1],"-",df[duplicated(df[,c(1,2)], fromLast = TRUE) | duplicated(df[,c(1,2)]),2])

> head(df)
    a   b c d       e
1 0.0 0.0 0 0     0-0
2 0.4 0.0 0 0   0.4-0
3 0.8 0.0 0 0   0.8-0
4 0.0 0.4 0 0   0-0.4
5 0.4 0.4 0 0 0.4-0.4
6 0.8 0.4 0 0 0.8-0.4
```

> Note : in this example, all rows are fitting original/duplicate criteria, therefore range assigned to all

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df$e <- paste(df$a,df$b)
```

Let me know if you were looking for something else

Comment: Potentially wrapping that with `factor` to get an underlying integer associated with the duplicate values.

Comment: could you give an example?